# Cannot return employeeType, but I can get displayName

Tags: asp.net

Can return all the usual attributes for a user in AD, but need to be able to return employeeType, and can't.

Tried using

```
DirectoryEntry dirEntry = (DirectoryEntry)ADUser.GetUnderlyingObject();
```

but still can't get at other attributes.

```
ActiveDirectory AD = new ActiveDirectory();
UserPrincipal ADUser = AD.GetUser(searchUsername);

DirectoryEntry dirEntry = (DirectoryEntry)ADUser.GetUnderlyingObject();

lblFullDN.Text = ADUser.DistinguishedName;
lblName.Text = ADUser.DisplayName;
lblEmailAddress.Text = ADUser.EmailAddress;
lblAccountStatus.Text = ADUser.Enabled.ToString();
lblPwdLastSet.Text = ADUser.LastPasswordSet.ToString();
lblBadLoginAttempts.Text = ADUser.BadLogonCount.ToString();
lblHomeDrive.Text = ADUser.HomeDrive;
lblADUsername.Text = ADUser.SamAccountName;
//doesn't work! nothing usable returned.
lblADEmployeeType.Text = dirEntry.Properties["employeeType"].Value.ToString();
```

Just want the attribute back to return to a page.

Comment: What are `lblFullDN` and the other variables? Does ADUser have a value?

Comment: Yes, all the rest are storing what I expected would be returned - it's when I try to get something other than the 'regular' variables, and apparently this is the way to do it, but nothing is being returned.

Comment: @wazz I'm not a C# developer, but judging by the first variable in the second code block, it looks like it means Active Directory.

Comment: I had a feeling, I just wanted the op to realize it's vague and all ADs should be updated, as well as the tags. :) ...